# Workflow framework that works with JSF

Tags: java, jpa, jsf-2, workflow

I need a workflow system for my JSF application. This will involve approvals, rejections, dual approvals, reassignment of the approval process. Users with certain roles and group permissions can approve/deny/change. I have not used any BPM tool before.

Wanted to know what are my choices given that I will be using JSF/JPA.

Thanks